# How to intercept request in servlet filter first before it hits the login jsp in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm taking over an existing Spring MVC project, and need to modify it's behavior, I added a servlet filter to intercept all incoming requests, some URLs of this app has the following format : http://example.com/SupportCenter/abc.html?token=some_token_value

I want to get the token value before anything else happens, but since this app has a security login page, if you are not logged in, and you try to get to the above URL, it will direct you to the login page at : http://example.com/SupportCenter/login.jsp

Therefore I won't be able intercept the incoming request url [ http://example.com/SupportCenter/abc.html ] and the token value, my app's web.xml looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <filter>
  <filter-name>Site_Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.builders.support.center.ServletFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Site_Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>supportCenter</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>supportCenter</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>supportCenter</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>supportCenter</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/newlogin</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 ...
 <login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <form-login-config>
   <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
   <form-error-page>/fail_login.html</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
 </login-config>
 <security-role>
  <role-name>1</role-name>
 </security-role>
 <security-role>
  <role-name>4</role-name>
 </security-role>
```

The supportCenter-servlet.xml looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--    - Application context definition for "SupportCenter" DispatcherServlet. -->
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.XYZ.support.center.weblayer.springmvc.controllers"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="supportCenterPropertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/properties/web-site.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
        </property>
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="urlMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/main.html">mainFormController</prop>

                <prop key="/login">mainFormController</prop>
                <prop key="/newlogin">mainFormController</prop>
                <prop key="/fail_login.html">failLoginViewController</prop>
                <prop key="/login.html">loginFormController</prop>

                <prop key="/changePassword.html">changePasswordFormController</prop>
                <prop key="/forgotUsername.html">forgotUsernameFormController</prop>
                <prop key="/forgotPassword.html">forgotPasswordFormController</prop>
...
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
...
    <bean id="mainFormController"
          class="com.XYZ.support.center.weblayer.springmvc.controllers.MainFormController">
        <property name="sessionForm">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property name="commandName">
            <value>commandBean</value>
        </property>
        <property name="commandClass">
            <value>com.XYZ.support.center.weblayer.springmvc.command.beans.MainCommandBean</value>
        </property>
        <property name="formView">
            <value>main</value>
        </property>
        <property name="successView">
            <value>main.html</value>
        </property>
        <property name="bindOnNewForm">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property name="equotesLink">
            <value>${equotes.link}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hotchkissAgencyBillPayLink">
            <value>${payment.pay.site.hotchkiss}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
...
    <bean id="loginFormController"
          class="com.XYZ.support.center.weblayer.springmvc.controllers.LoginFormController">
        <property name="sessionForm">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property name="commandName">
            <value>commandBean</value>
        </property>
        <property name="commandClass">
            <value>com.XYZ.support.center.weblayer.springmvc.command.beans.LoginCommandBean</value>
        </property>
        <property name="formView">
            <value>login</value>
       </property>
        <property name="successView">
            <value>j_security_check</value>
        </property>
        <property name="bindOnNewForm">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
...
</beans>
```

My filter looks like this :

```
public class ServletFilter implements Filter
{
  String requestURI="",url="",queryString="",Token="";

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,ServletResponse servletResponse,FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException,ServletException
  {
    if (servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest)
    {
      requestURI=(HttpServletRequest)servletRequest.getRequestURI();
      url=((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest).getRequestURL().toString();
      queryString=((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest).getQueryString();
    }
    System.out.println("  [ Intercepted In ServletFilter = 0 ]  requestURI = "+requestURI+"  ,  url = "+url+"  ,  queryString = "+queryString);
...
   }
}
```

And the output of trying to reach [ /SupportCenter/abc.html?token=some_token_value ] looks like this :

```
Aug 13, 2014 6:26:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 54325 ms
  [ JSP = 1 ] 1407968732269
  [ JSP = 2 ] 1407968732677
  [ Intercepted In ServletFilter = 0 ]  requestURI = /SupportCenter/styles/loginForm.css  ,  url = http://10.xx.5.2/SupportCenter/styles/loginForm.css  ,  queryString = null
  [ Intercepted In ServletFilter = 1 ]  Token = null  ,  url = http://10.xx.5.2/SupportCenter/styles/loginForm.css
  [ queryString = null ]
  [ Intercepted In ServletFilter = 0 ]  requestURI = /SupportCenter/javascript/login.js  ,  url = http://10.xx.5.2/SupportCenter/javascript/login.js  ,  queryString = null
  [ Intercepted In ServletFilter = 1 ]  Token = null  ,  url = http://10.xx.5.2/SupportCenter/javascript/login.js
  [ queryString = null ]
  [ Intercepted In ServletFilter = 0 ]  requestURI = /SupportCenter/styles/header_ms.css  ,  url = http://10.xx.5.2/SupportCenter/styles/header_ms.css  ,  queryString = null
  [ Intercepted In ServletFilter = 1 ]  Token = null  ,  url = http://10.xx.5.2/SupportCenter/styles/header_ms.css
  [ queryString = null ]
```

As you can see, it reaches the JSP page first. What can I do so it hits the servlet filter first ? And even if there's no way it can reach the filter first, how to get the token value when it's redirected to the login.jsp ?

My 2nd question is : how to bypass the login.jsp all together ?

Comment: There is not enough code/information here to answer your question. You are going to have to do a bit more work yourself to understand how your app works, how URLs map to various controllers and/or JSP pages, etc and how the security is wired in (so to disable the login, etc). I don't think it will help posting the entire contents of the Spring MVC app. Once you have narrowed it down to a more specific issue, then try again here.

Comment: It also looks like the filter is only getting triggered on JS/CSS files, not for your actual JSP page... Filters should always get triggered before JSP or controller code, so I think you're wrong in saying it "reaches the JSP page first"... its not reaching the filter at all.