# Why is SavedRequest null in Java Spring app?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

This is related to a previous question : [How to intercept request in servlet filter first before it hits the login jsp in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297316/how-to-intercept-request-in-servlet-filter-first-before-it-hits-the-login-jsp-in)

I did some research and found there is a SavedRequest object that saves original URL, so in my login.jsp I have the following lines :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>

<%@ page import="org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<%
   System.out.println("  [ JSP = 1 ] "+new Date().getTime());

   SavedRequest savedRequest=new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request,response);
   System.out.println("  [ JSP = 1.1 ]  savedRequest == null ? "+(savedRequest == null));
   String requestUrl=savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
   System.out.println(" requestUrl = "+requestUrl);
%>
...
```

But the output was :

```
INFO: Server startup in 54732 ms
  [ JSP = 1 ] 1407987538402
  [ JSP = 1.1 ]  savedRequest == null ? true
Aug 13, 2014 11:38:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I clicked on a URL [ something like : http://example.com/supportCenter/mainPage.html?token=XYZ ] before login, and was sent to the login.jsp, so in the login.jsp I expect to get the original URL [ http://example.com/supportCenter/mainPage.html?token=XYZ ] from the requestUrl, but the savedRequest was null, why ?

Comment: I'm guessing because you aren't supposed to use a _new_ `HttpSessionRequestCache`, but an existing one.

Comment: You should not be writing Java code in JSPs - its considered an anti-pattern these days. Consider writing a taglib if you can't put that code into your controller.

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis : In my case, how to get an existing one ?

Comment: I didn't get that notification :( Don't put any spaces between `@username`. I don't actually know Spring security very well. I'd think something has to actually save it. For example, if you sent a request that needs authentication, you'd get redirected to login page, login, and then get redirected back to the original, saved, request. I'd look at the components that filter your requests.